# Смена картинки в item Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте. Уже которую неделю не могу решить проблему. Имеется кастомный Listview и адаптер наследованный от SimpleCursorAdapter. В методе getView заполняю Listview и устанавливаю слушатель на imageView:

```
holder.update.setOnClickListener(onUpdateListener(cursor.getPosition(),holder.progress));
```

При нажатии на imageView в определенном item'e, imageview должен скрыться и на его месте показаться progressbar. Но это все происходит на нужном и каждом третьем item'е. Разметка item есть ничто иное как LinearLayout с виджетами textview и imageview.

Вот код слушателя:

```
private View.OnClickListener onUpdateListener(final int position,final ProgressBar progress) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    };
}
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Покажите целиком getView метод. Общая идея такова - вам надо в этом методе прописать if-else в котором определять по позиции должен ли быть показан прогресс или нет.

Comment: Вот так и сделал уже.По нажатию на обновить запомнил позицию item нажатой картинки передал в asynctask,там же картинку скрыл прогресс показал, и уже в getView проверяю если позиция равна моей то картинку скрыл прогресс показал если нет то картинку показал прогресс скрыл только так.Пробывал через setTag/getTag но результата не добился.

Comment: Вам нужно не только явно устанавливать свой прогрессбар в айтемах, где он требуется, но и так же явно убирать его там, где он не требуется. По теме переиспользования айтемов в `ListView` \ `RecyclerView` написано уже достаточно здесь, а поиск еще работает. В `CursorAdapter` и его наследниках переопределяется методы `NewView()` и `BindView()`, а не `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

При переиспользовании не удаляется установленный слушатель.
Попробуйте внутри клик листенера проверять установленную позицию / или по умолчанию элементу удалять (или не создавать) слушатель.